# Is there anyway to change a dataframe in pandas to have the index in the middle?

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a data frame showing two teams comparing to each other. I'd like to change the data frame to look similar to a graphic you see on TV. Is this possible in Pandas?

```
        Shooting  Rebounds  FieldGoal
Team 1  Team1Stat Team1Stat Team1Stat
Team 2  Team2Stat Team2Stat Team2Stat
```

What I'd like it to look like:

```
       Team1               Team2
     Team1Stat  Shooting   Team2Stat
     Team1Stat  Rebounds   Team2Stat
     Team1Stat  FieldGoal  Team2Stat
```

Is this at all possible? What I'm thinking is something along the lines that you see on ESPN that shows a side-by-side comparison of the two teams. I know I can use

```
df1.transpose()
```

But that will only get me to have the index to the left and I'm looking to get it in the middle of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Index. If you really want to achieve the result visually,
you can just create a DataFrame with 3 separate columns e.g. Team1, Category, Team2

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for aesthetic purpose, this is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

# for read_clipboard()
'''
Shooting    Rebounds    FieldGoal
Team1   Team1Stat   Team1Stat   Team1Stat
Team2   Team2Stat   Team2Stat   Team2Stat
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\t+')

df_new = df.T.reset_index()
df_new = df_new[['Team1', 'index', 'Team2']]
df_new.columns = ['Team1', '', 'Team2']

print(df_new)
```

Output:

```
       Team1                 Team2
0  Team1Stat   Shooting  Team2Stat
1  Team1Stat   Rebounds  Team2Stat
2  Team1Stat  FieldGoal  Team2Stat
```